# Ios - Twitter API getting user info issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, parse-platform

I'm trying to add Login and Register to my app via Twitter this my code for getting twitter user info :

```
-(void) initWithTwitterUser{


[SVProgressHUD show];
_nameField.text = [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName;

// TODO find a way to fetch details with Twitter..
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

NSString * requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=%@", [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName];
NSURL *verify = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:verify];
[[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:request];


// TODO find a way to fetch details with Twitter..
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];


if (!error){
    NSDictionary* result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);

    [user setObject:[result objectForKey:@"profile_image_url_https"]
             forKey:@"picture"];
    // does this thign help?
    [user setUsername:[result objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];

    NSString * names = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[names componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
    if ( array.count > 1){
        [user setObject:[array lastObject]
                 forKey:@"last_name"];

        [array removeLastObject];
        [user setObject:[array componentsJoinedByString:@" " ]
                 forKey:@"first_name"];
    }

} else
    NSLog(@"Error : %@ ", [error userInfo]);
}
```

Login via twitter works fine but the problem after login when I try to get user info I get this issue

> Error : {
>       NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=karizma_ltd";
>       NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=karizma_ltd";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)\" UserInfo=0x15ec8bc0 {_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey={url = https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=karizma_ltd}}";
>   }

Comment: try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17083649/1091539

Comment: @Mutawe any other solution without using that library

Comment: Looks like a bug. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307062/access-users-ios-default-twitter-account-ios/30461959#30461959

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was error related to parse.com sdk version `1.8.1`or `1.8.0`, I can't remember the exact version sorry, it was resolved in next sdk version